# getElementById with unique id from model

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have a view with the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m[i].Reviews[0].Quantity)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m[i].Reviews[0].Price)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m[i].Reviews[0].Value)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @for (var j = 0; j < Model[i].Reviews.Count; j++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Reviews[j].TempId)
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Reviews[j].Quantity, new { id = "quantity", onblur = "calculateValue()" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Reviews[j].Quantity)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Reviews[j].Price, new { id = "price", onblur = "calculateValue()" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Reviews[j].Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Reviews[j].Value, new { id = "value", @readonly = true })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Reviews[j].Value)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
}
```

In this view, I also have some JavaScript to calculate Value by the product of Price and Quantity:

```
function calculateValue() {
    var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;

    var value = price * quantity;
    document.getElementById("value").value = parseFloat(value);
}
```

The question is an obvious one and I assume painfully simple to answer, however I have almost zero knowledge of JS...so here goes:

Given I'm using the `getElementById` method and have multiple HTML elements (for each row in my table) currently sharing the same element ids of `price`, `quantity` and `value`...the current implementation won't work. How do I then assign unique ids, appending the model's `TempId` as the unique identifier and then using these unique ids for both calculation in my JS function as well as for displaying the corresponding `Value` in the table?

Comment: You cannot re-use "id" values. They need to be unique for the whole page.

Comment: @Pointy...I know that, that's what I implied in my post.

Comment: you can use the counter variable of the loop so for example it "value" + @j.

Comment: Dont assign id's MVC will automatically put unique id's on those elements

Comment: @illya you're right, sorry to have misunderstood.

Comment: Hmm @code, looks like it's not entirely working. It's working for the first row: I can type in different numbers for price and quantity and value will be updated. However, none of the subsequent rows work, value is not refreshed when I change the numbers for price and quantity.

Comment: Yes thats because the id's are now specific you have to know what you're looking for

Comment: @code, I guess my question then is how would I reference the correct ID in my JS function?

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: @code, yes I have both jQuery and jQueryUI included in my project.

Comment: @lksmth has a good example of how to attack this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use jQuery and change your ids to classes and do something like the following. This will eliminate the need for generating anything unique for your input elements.

```js
$('.quantity, .price').on('blur', function(e) {
  var $parentRow = $(this).parents('tr');
  var quantity = parseInt($parentRow.find('.quantity').val());
  var price = parseInt($parentRow.find('.price').val());
  $parentRow.find('.value').val(quantity * price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="quantity" value="3">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="price" value="3">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="value">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @lksmth, rewriting this to fit my impl. I've removed the `onblur` from my `<td>` elements however looks like something is stopping the new function from being triggered when I type values in price and quantity and click out. No errors in my Developer tools Console window.

Comment: How does your new html look?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to change the ids to classes. It's working fine now, will mark this as the answer. Aside: not sure if any of you use ReSharper with Visual Studio, but do you handle the "unknown CSS class 'price'" warnings that will now show up all over the code?

Comment: @illya, do you mean -  removed `onblur` from your `input` elements. Make sure the `input` elements in the `td`s have the right classes. Ok I just read your update. I don't know very much about ReSharper - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the textboxes for Quantity, Price, and Value would automatically get ids in the format as exemplified below, if you do not explicitly specify id like id="quantity" in your html; (one thing though I am not sure how did you happen to have Model[i] and m => m[i], so I am exemplifying in case where it is @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Reviews[j].Quantity instead):

```
Reviews_1__Quantity
Reviews_1__Price
Reviews_1__Value
```

So in your javascript for onblur function (pass id to this function), you could make use of this naming convention for id to get values for Quantity, Price and calculate Value:

```
var reviewId = id.substr(0, id.lastIndexOf('_') + 1); // will return Reviews_1__
var qty = $('#' + reviewId + 'Quantity').val(); // Reviews_1__Quantity
var price = $('#' + reviewId + 'Price').val(); // Reviews_1__Price
var total = qty * price;
$('#' + reviewId + 'Value').val(total); // Reviews_1__Value
```